# Bootstrap dropdown-item are not vertically stacked in Windows 8.1 but they are in windows 7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm using the [following example](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#example) where dropdown items are vertically stacked in windows 7 but not in windows 8.1. What may be missing? Both machines are using IE 11 and latest version of Chrome. Both browsers in windows 8.1 have the same issue. Both machines are using same latest versions of Bootstrap and jquery via Visual Studio 2015 in an ASP.NET Core CR2 app.

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown open">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Windows 8.1 shows following:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Both machines are using the same ASP.NET Core app project in VS2015 and both machines have the exact same `bower.json file` as shown below (that also shows that Bootstrap 4-alpha is loaded):

**bower.json file**:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "jquery-validation": "1.15.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": ">=1.8",
    "jquery-validation": "1.15.0"
  }
}
```

Moreover, the source view of the generated html file on both machines is showing the following stylesheets in `<head>...</head>` section and script tags at the bottom of the `<body>...</body>` section:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home Page - ASP.NET Core RC2 Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</haed>
<body>
....
.....
   <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script src="/js/site.js?v=EWaMeWsJBYWmL2g_KkgXZQ5nPe-a3Ichp0LEgzXczKo"></script>
</body>
```

**UPDATE 2**:

I'm using the Development environment. The console tab in the Chrome's development tool shows no errors. Following is the **Image of Dependencies folder** that shows that bootstrap 4-alpha was installed. I also updated this file by right clicking it and clicking on `Update` menu. When I copy the source view of the generated HTML file in win8 to win7 and change the paths of styleesheets ans scripts to the paths of these files in win7 project the dropdown correctly displays as expected. It seems something not right in steelsheet and scripts files on win8. I also uninstalled amd reinstalled .NET Core on win8. But still the same issue.:

[image]

Comment: You're example markup is from Bootstrap [v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/) but it looks like you may be using the assests (CSS/JS) from [v3](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns), they aren't interchangeable.

Comment: This is something related to browser not related to OS. Please upgrade your browser and try again by clearing your browser cache.

Comment: @vanburen I've tried same example with both Bootstrap V4 and V3 on both the machines. It works fine on win 7 both not on win 8.1

Comment: @JigneshPatel I'm using the latest versions of IE11 and Chrome after clearing the cache. The same example work on win7 but not on win 8.1

Comment: @vanburen I've added an UPDATE section to my post showing the `bower.json` file and the `source view` of the generated HTML file on both machines

Comment: I can only guess that you haven't actually updated to v4 in Bower, if you check inside **Solution Explorer: Dependencies / Bower**  is there an error because you probably will have to manually update this by right clicking _Bootstrap (4.0.0.-alpha.2)_ & select Update Package. You will also have to change your dependencies for **Staging & Development** inside `_Layout.cshtml` since these reference Bootstrap v3 as well as reference [tether.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17273) since you'll see an error in your console as some Bootstrap components rely on this. Hope this helps.

Comment: @vanburen I've added UPDATE 2 to my post that shows the image of Dependencies folder where, per your suggestion, I updated the Bootstrap (4.0.0.-alpha.2) as well. The `_Layout.cshtml` shows the stylesheet and script files path same as shown in my post that are same in win7 where the dropdown works as expected. bootstrap v4 was installed using bowser.json and I could see in output windows of VS2015 that was showing the successful installation process. The same installation process was used in win7 and no change was manually made to `_Layout.cshtml` file in win7 as well. Win8.1 still same issue.

Comment: You're saying that if you open up the actual CSS file through the browser to check that **v4** is loading yet still not working? I didn't have any issues with WIN7, WIN8 or WIN10 so I can only imagine it's a problem that's local to your setup.